# Let $G$ be a group and suppose that $a*b*c=e$ for all $a,b,c \in G$, show that $c*b*a=e$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I'm really in the dark here:

$a*b*c=e=identity$

$a*e=e*a, b*e=e*b, c*e=e*c$

$a*b*c=e$

$e=e$

$c*e*b=e*c*b$

$c*a*b*c*b=a*b*c*b*c*e=c*b$

$c*a*b*c*b=a*b*c*b*c*e=c*b*a*b*c$

$c*a*b*c*b=c*b*a*b*c$

$c*a*b*c*b*a*b*c=c*b*a*b*c$

$c*b*a*b=c*b*a*b$

$(a*b*c)^{-1}=c^{-1}*b^{-1}*a^{-1}$

$a*b*c=c^{-1}*b^{-1}*a^{-1}$

$a=c^{-1}*b^{-1}$

$b=c^{-1}*a^{-1}$

$c=b^{-1}*a^{-1}$

$c*b*a=b^{-1}*a^{-1}*c^{-1}*a^{-1}*c^{-1}*b^{-1}$

No matter what I try I can't seem to mirror the $a*b*c$  on one side and keep the identity on the other. I just get $c*b*a=c*b*a$

Edit: Did misread the assignment so changed title from

Let $G$ be a group and suppose that $a*b*c=e$, show that $c*b*a=e$ for all $a,b,c \in G$

to

Let $G$ be a group and suppose that $a*b*c=e$ for all $a,b,c \in G$, show that $c*b*a=e$

Comment: Is the assumption that $\forall a,b,c\in G$, $a*b*c=e$?

Comment: No, the title is written directly off the assignment I got. So I suppose G can be $S_3$ for example.

Comment: I'm sure that the assumptions are listed incorrectly. For otherwise we have the following simple argument. Let $a\in G$ be arbitrary. The selections $b=c=e$ and the assumption imply that
$$
e=a*b*c=a*e*e=a*e=a.
$$
Therefore all the elements of $G$ are equal to $e$. In particular $c*b*a=e$, because $c*b*a$ is an element of $G$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1468368/how-to-solve-this-type-of-easy-problems-of-simple-permutations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the assumption is that $\forall a,b,c\in G$, $a*b*c=e$, then letting $a'=c,b'=b,c'=a$, we have: $c'*b'*a'=a*b*c=e$, and therefore, relabeling yields $c*b*a=e$.

Otherwise, if this only holds for some $a,b,c\in G$, then it is not true in general, as it would require $a*b=b*a$ by the uniqueness of inverses.

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$I:=\begin{pmatrix}i&0\\0&-i\end{pmatrix}\text{, } J:=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\text{, } K:=\begin{pmatrix}0&i\\i&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Then :

$$IJK=\begin{pmatrix}0&-i\\-i&0\end{pmatrix}K=I_2 $$

Whereas :

$$KJI=K\begin{pmatrix}0&i\\i&0\end{pmatrix}=-I_2 $$

So the property is false in $G=GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ (in $\mathbb{Q}_8$ actually).

Answer (score 1):

This is not true in general.  Let $G$ be $S_3$, and take  $a = (1,2)$, $b= (2, 3)$ and $c =(a*b)^{-1}= (1, 2, 3)^{-1}= (1, 3, 2)$.  Then $a*b*c = e$, but $c$ is not the inverse of $b*a = (1, 2,3 )$, so $c*b*a \neq e$.

For a general example, let $a$ and $b$ be any two non-commuting elements in a group $G$, and let $c = (a*b)^{-1}$.  Then $a*b *c = e$, but $c$ cannot also be  the inverse of $b*a$, so $c*b*a\neq e$.